# Load nested JSON Data into HTML <UL> <LI> list....>

Tags: javascript, json, html-lists, nested-lists

To start with, the environment:

- node js
- express
- mySQL
- plain old Javascript (no frameworks used)

I'm reading a List of F1 Circuits by Country from a MySQL Database, getting the output in JSON and I would like to load the data into an HTML Page using javascript on the client side, this being the desired format:

- Country:

  - Race Track Name
  - Race Track 2 Name
- Country 2:

  - Race Track Name
- Country 3:
  [Dont show anything if no track exists]

Some Countries do not have a track at all, some have 1 race track, and other countries have seceral race tracks as shown in this JSON output from my SQL Query:
[image: JSON Output]

As shown in the pic, Country at Index 0 has no track, Country at Index 10 has 1 track, Country at Index 14 has more than 1 track.

Im stuck at the point to read that JSON Data into a loop and load it into the page in the appropriate <LI> elements to display as shown above (including the nesting).

The problem I have is I cant make sense of how to read this JSON format as it is not in the normal format that I receive it from my other queries. I get all this extra "Country:" tag at the start of each line and the actual data is full of \ so I dont know how to read it.
I tried .stringify, I tried .parse but cant just extract the country name or track name in a variable.

I have the following eventlistener and function defined:

```js
// Add an event listener to load the sidebar with the list of F1 Circuits once the DOM has completed loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    fetch('http://192.168.68.102:3000/loadF1Circuits')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseData => loadCircuits(responseData['data']));
  });


  
  function loadCircuits(circuitsList) {
    const circuitsUL_List = document.querySelector("#circuits");
    let htmlToLoad = "";

    for (const racingEvent of circuitsList) {
  
    }
    circuitsUL_List.innerHTML=htmlToLoad;
  }
```

and this is my SQL query in order to get the data nested by country:

```js
    async getAllCircuitsByCountry() {
        try {
            const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const query = 
                `
                select  json_object (
                            'Country', Countries.cnt_name,
                            'circuits', (select cast(concat('[', GROUP_CONCAT(json_object('Circuits_ID', Circuits.crt_ID, 'Circuit_name', Circuits.crt_name)),']')  as JSON) 
                                        FROM    Circuits 
                                        WHERE   Countries.cnt_name = Circuits.crt_country_name)) 
                            as Country 
                FROM    Countries
                ORDER BY Countries.cnt_name;`;

                connection.query(query, (err, results) => {
                    if (err) reject(new Error(err.message));
                    resolve(results);
                })
            });
            return response;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        };
    };
```

This is the JSON Data I get in answer to the comment below, there the array has 264 objects so quite long, which is why I didnt paste the whole output in the first place but showed a screen shot at the top instead:

```js
{"data":[{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Afghanistan\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Aland Islands\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Albania\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Algeria\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"American Samoa\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Andorra\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Angola\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Anguilla\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Antarctica\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Antigua and Barbuda\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Argentina\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 25, \"Circuit_name\": \"Autódromo Juan y Oscar Gálvez\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Armenia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Aruba\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Ascension Island\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Australia\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 1, \"Circuit_name\": \"Albert Park Grand Prix Circuit\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 29, \"Circuit_name\": \"Adelaide Street Circuit\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Austria\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 23, \"Circuit_name\": \"A1-Ring\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 57, \"Circuit_name\": \"Zeltweg\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 70, \"Circuit_name\": \"Red Bull Ring\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Azerbaijan\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 73, \"Circuit_name\": \"Baku City Circuit\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Bahamas\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Bahrain\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 3, \"Circuit_name\": \"Bahrain International Circuit\"}]}"}"}]}
```

By changing my SQL Query as follows:

```js
                SELECT      Countries.cnt_name, Circuits.crt_name
                FROM        Countries
                LEFT JOIN   Circuits
                ON          Countries.cnt_name = Circuits.crt_country_name
                ORDER BY    Countries.cnt_name;`;
```

I get a different JSON format but then I get several objects for the same Country if a country has more than once track, as per this JSON Output:

```js
{"data":[{"cnt_name":"Afghanistan","crt_name":null},{"cnt_name":"Aland Islands","crt_name":null},{"cnt_name":"Albania","crt_name":null},{"cnt_name":"Algeria","crt_name":null},{"cnt_name":"American Samoa","crt_name":null},{"cnt_name":"Andorra","crt_name":null},{"cnt_name":"Angola","crt_name":null},{"cnt_name":"Anguilla","crt_name":null},{"cnt_name":"Antarctica","crt_name":null},{"cnt_name":"Antigua and Barbuda","crt_name":null},{"cnt_name":"Argentina","crt_name":"Autódromo Juan y Oscar Gálvez"},{"cnt_name":"Armenia","crt_name":null},{"cnt_name":"Aruba","crt_name":null},{"cnt_name":"Ascension Island","crt_name":null},{"cnt_name":"Australia","crt_name":"Albert Park Grand Prix Circuit"},{"cnt_name":"Australia","crt_name":"Adelaide Street Circuit"},{"cnt_name":"Austria","crt_name":"A1-Ring"},{"cnt_name":"Austria","crt_name":"Zeltweg"},{"cnt_name":"Austria","crt_name":"Red Bull Ring"},{"cnt_name":"Azerbaijan","crt_name":"Baku City Circuit"},{"cnt_name":"Bahamas","crt_name":null},{"cnt_name":"Bahrain","crt_name":"Bahrain International Circuit"}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction please on how to read the data from that JSON output.

Thank you in advance.
M.

Comment: Imagine how useful it would be to NOT post the SQL if that works but instead post an example of the JSON output. THEN we could help. If you then went so far as to click [edit] and then `[<>]` snippet editor with your attempt in a [mcve] instead of just code, then we could help you even quicker

Comment: But FIRST [have a search](https://www.google.com/search?q=nested+json+li+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Can you run ```typeof data[0]["Country"] ?
It looks like it's a String while you are expecting an Object...

Comment: LauDem: you are right, it turns out to be a string, when I console.log(typeof circuitsList[0]["Country"]); in the function above, it comes back saying String

Comment: mplungian: thanks for link to the other postings. I actually did do that type of search too but whilst I found plenty that explain how to loop through the data and upload it into the LI, I couldnt find any that explains how to actually read the data from the JSON output with the \ and the extra repeating tag at the start of each object

Comment: It took me longer to write a solution because I had to first interpret your invalid JSON - a much shorter string would have been preferred - it is called [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my version using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

You can improve this by returning a proper JSON data instead of nested JSON strings.

I could bypass it by replacing all sorts of stuff

Remove the first two lines when you have fixed the JSON on the server

```js
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll(/\\/g,"").replaceAll(/"{/g,"{").replaceAll(/}"}/g,"}}")
const circuitsList = JSON.parse(jsonString).data;
document.getElementById("circuits").innerHTML = circuitsList.map(({Country}) => {
  const [country, circuits] = Object.values(Country);
  const circuitUl = circuits && circuits.length ?  `<ul>${circuits.map(circuit=>`<li>${circuit.Circuit_name}</li>`).join('')}</ul>` : '';
  return `<li>${country} ${circuitUl}</li>`
  }).join("");
```

```html
<ul id="circuits"></ul>
<script>let jsonString = `{"data":[{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Afghanistan\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Aland Islands\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Albania\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Algeria\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"American Samoa\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Andorra\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Angola\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Anguilla\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Antarctica\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Antigua and Barbuda\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Argentina\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 25, \"Circuit_name\": \"Autódromo Juan y Oscar Gálvez\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Armenia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Aruba\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Ascension Island\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Australia\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 1, \"Circuit_name\": \"Albert Park Grand Prix Circuit\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 29, \"Circuit_name\": \"Adelaide Street Circuit\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Austria\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 23, \"Circuit_name\": \"A1-Ring\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 57, \"Circuit_name\": \"Zeltweg\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 70, \"Circuit_name\": \"Red Bull Ring\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Azerbaijan\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 73, \"Circuit_name\": \"Baku City Circuit\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Bahamas\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Bahrain\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 3, \"Circuit_name\": \"Bahrain International Circuit\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Bangladesh\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Barbados\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Belarus\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Belgium\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 13, \"Circuit_name\": \"Circuit de Spa-Francorchamps\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 40, \"Circuit_name\": \"Zolder\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 50, \"Circuit_name\": \"Nivelles-Baulers\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Belize\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Benin\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Bermuda\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Bhutan\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Bolivia (Plurinational State of)\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Bosnia and Herzegovina\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Botswana\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Bouvet Island\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Brazil\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 18, \"Circuit_name\": \"Autódromo José Carlos Pace\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 36, \"Circuit_name\": \"Autódromo Internacional Nelson Piquet\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"British Indian Ocean Territory\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Brunei Darussalam\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Bulgaria\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Burkina Faso\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Burundi\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Cabo Verde\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Cambodia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Cameroon\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Canada\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 7, \"Circuit_name\": \"Circuit Gilles Villeneuve\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 48, \"Circuit_name\": \"Mosport International Raceway\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 52, \"Circuit_name\": \"Circuit Mont-Tremblant\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Canary Islands\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Catalonia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Cayman Islands\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Central African Republic\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Ceuta & Melilla\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Chad\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Chile\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"China\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 17, \"Circuit_name\": \"Shanghai International Circuit\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Christmas Island\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Clipperton Island\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Cocos (Keeling) Islands\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Colombia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Comoros\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Cook Islands\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Costa Rica\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Côte d'Ivoire\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Croatia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Cuba\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Curaçao\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Cyprus\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Czech Republic\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Democratic Republic of the Congo\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Denmark\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Diego Garcia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Djibouti\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Dominica\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Dominican Republic\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Ecuador\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Egypt\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"El Salvador\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"England\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Equatorial Guinea\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Eritrea\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Estonia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Ethiopia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Europe\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Falkland Islands\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Faroe Islands\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Federated States of Micronesia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Fiji\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Finland\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"France\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 8, \"Circuit_name\": \"Circuit de Nevers Magny-Cours\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 34, \"Circuit_name\": \"Circuit Paul Ricard\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 41, \"Circuit_name\": \"Dijon-Prenois\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 51, \"Circuit_name\": \"Charade Circuit\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 53, \"Circuit_name\": \"Rouen-Les-Essarts\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 54, \"Circuit_name\": \"Le Mans\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 55, \"Circuit_name\": \"Reims-Gueux\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"French Guiana\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"French Polynesia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"French Southern Territories\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Gabon\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Galicia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Gambia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Georgia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Germany\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 10, \"Circuit_name\": \"Hockenheimring\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 20, \"Circuit_name\": \"Nürburgring\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 61, \"Circuit_name\": \"AVUS\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Ghana\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Gibraltar\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Greece\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Greenland\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Grenada\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Guadeloupe\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Guam\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Guatemala\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Guernsey\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Guinea\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Guinea-Bissau\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Guyana\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Haiti\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Heard Island and McDonald Islands\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Holy See\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Honduras\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Hong Kong\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Hungary\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 11, \"Circuit_name\": \"Hungaroring\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Iceland\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"India\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 68, \"Circuit_name\": \"Buddh International Circuit\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Indonesia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Iran (Islamic Republic of)\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Iraq\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Ireland\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Isle of Man\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Israel\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Italy\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 14, \"Circuit_name\": \"Autodromo Nazionale di Monza\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 21, \"Circuit_name\": \"Autodromo Enzo e Dino Ferrari\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 65, \"Circuit_name\": \"Pescara Circuit\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 76, \"Circuit_name\": \"Autodromo Internazionale del Mugello\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Jamaica\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Japan\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 16, \"Circuit_name\": \"Fuji Speedway\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 22, \"Circuit_name\": \"Suzuka Circuit\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 28, \"Circuit_name\": \"Okayama International Circuit\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Jersey\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Jordan\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Kazakhstan\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Kenya\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Kiribati\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Kosovo\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Kuwait\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Kyrgyzstan\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Laos\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Latvia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Lebanon\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Lesotho\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Liberia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Libya\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Liechtenstein\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Lithuania\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Luxembourg\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Macau\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Madagascar\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Malawi\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Malaysia\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 2, \"Circuit_name\": \"Sepang International Circuit\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Maldives\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Mali\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Malta\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Marshall Islands\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Martinique\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Mauritania\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Mauritius\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Mayotte\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Mexico\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 32, \"Circuit_name\": \"Autódromo Hermanos Rodríguez\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Moldova\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Monaco\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 6, \"Circuit_name\": \"Circuit de Monaco\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Mongolia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Montenegro\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Montserrat\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Morocco\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 64, \"Circuit_name\": \"Ain Diab\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Mozambique\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Myanmar\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Namibia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Nauru\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Nepal\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Netherlands\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 39, \"Circuit_name\": \"Circuit Park Zandvoort\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"New Caledonia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"New Zealand\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Nicaragua\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Niger\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Nigeria\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Niue\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Norfolk Island\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"North Korea\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"North Macedonia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Northern Ireland\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Northern Mariana Islands\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Norway\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Oman\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Pakistan\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Palau\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Panama\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Papua New Guinea\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Paraguay\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Peru\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Philippines\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Pitcairn\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Poland\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Portugal\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 27, \"Circuit_name\": \"Autódromo do Estoril\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 59, \"Circuit_name\": \"Circuito da Boavista\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 62, \"Circuit_name\": \"Monsanto Park Circuit\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 75, \"Circuit_name\": \"Autódromo Internacional do Algarve\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Puerto Rico\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Qatar\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 78, \"Circuit_name\": \"Losail International Circuit\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Republic of the Congo\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Réunion\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Romania\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Russia\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 71, \"Circuit_name\": \"Sochi Autodrom\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Rwanda\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Saint Barthélemy\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Saint Kitts and Nevis\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Saint Lucia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Saint Martin\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Saint Pierre and Miquelon\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Samoa\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"San Marino\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Sao Tome and Principe\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Saudi Arabia\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 77, \"Circuit_name\": \"Jeddah Street Circuit\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Scotland\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Senegal\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Serbia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Seychelles\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Sierra Leone\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Singapore\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 15, \"Circuit_name\": \"Marina Bay Street Circuit\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Sint Maarten\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Slovakia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Slovenia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Solomon Islands\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Somalia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"South Africa\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 30, \"Circuit_name\": \"Kyalami\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 56, \"Circuit_name\": \"Prince George Circuit\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"South Korea\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"South Sudan\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Spain\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 4, \"Circuit_name\": \"Circuit de Barcelona-Catalunya\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 12, \"Circuit_name\": \"Valencia Street Circuit\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 26, \"Circuit_name\": \"Circuito de Jerez\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 45, \"Circuit_name\": \"Jarama\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 49, \"Circuit_name\": \"Montjuïc\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 67, \"Circuit_name\": \"Circuit de Pedralbes\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Sri Lanka\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"State of Palestine\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Sudan\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Suriname\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Svalbard and Jan Mayen\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Swaziland\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Sweden\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 47, \"Circuit_name\": \"Scandinavian Raceway\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Switzerland\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 66, \"Circuit_name\": \"Circuit Bremgarten\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Syrian Arab Republic\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Taiwan\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Tajikistan\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Tanzania\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Thailand\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Timor-Leste\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Togo\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Tokelau\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Tonga\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Trinidad and Tobago\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Tristan da Cunha\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Tunisia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Turkey\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 5, \"Circuit_name\": \"Istanbul Park\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Turkmenistan\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Turks and Caicos Islands\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Tuvalu\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Uganda\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Ukraine\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"United Arab Emirates\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 24, \"Circuit_name\": \"Yas Marina Circuit\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"United Kingdom\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 9, \"Circuit_name\": \"Silverstone Circuit\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 31, \"Circuit_name\": \"Donington Park\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 38, \"Circuit_name\": \"Brands Hatch\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 58, \"Circuit_name\": \"Aintree\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"United Nations\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"United States Minor Outlying Islands\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"United States of America\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 19, \"Circuit_name\": \"Indianapolis Motor Speedway\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 33, \"Circuit_name\": \"Phoenix street circuit\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 37, \"Circuit_name\": \"Detroit Street Circuit\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 42, \"Circuit_name\": \"Fair Park\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 43, \"Circuit_name\": \"Long Beach\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 44, \"Circuit_name\": \"Las Vegas Street Circuit\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 46, \"Circuit_name\": \"Watkins Glen\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 60, \"Circuit_name\": \"Riverside International Raceway\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 63, \"Circuit_name\": \"Sebring International Raceway\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 69, \"Circuit_name\": \"Circuit of the Americas\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 72, \"Circuit_name\": \"Port Imperial Street Circuit\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Uruguay\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Uzbekistan\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Vanuatu\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Venezuela\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Vietnam\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 74, \"Circuit_name\": \"Hanoi Street Circuit\"}]}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Virgin Islands (British)\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Virgin Islands (U.S.)\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Wales\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Wallis and Futuna\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Western Sahara\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Yemen\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Zambia\", \"circuits\": null}"},{"Country":"{\"Country\": \"Zimbabwe\", \"circuits\": null}"}]}`</script>
```

Comment: thank you mplungian. The reason I used the (more complicated) nested string format is that I wasnt sure how to deal with countries with more than one circuit. I created a different SQL query with a LEFT JOIN which gives me an output Im more used to dealing with but I get more than one object per country for countries that have more than one circuit. Ive added the JSON of that output in my original posting

Comment: I know. I am using that JSON

Answer (score 0):

[`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) will be handy here to interpret the data as objects. Once that is done you can iterate through the list of countries adding to the main `<ul>`. If the circuit list is not `null`, create a new `<ul>` and append circuit names to that list.

```js
const data = [{
    "Country": "{\"Country\": \"Aruba\", \"circuits\": null}"
  },
  {
    "Country": "{\"Country\": \"Ascension Island\", \"circuits\": null}"
  },
  {
    "Country": "{\"Country\": \"Australia\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 1, \"Circuit_name\": \"Albert Park Grand Prix Circuit\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 29, \"Circuit_name\": \"Adelaide Street Circuit\"}]}"
  },
  {
    "Country": "{\"Country\": \"Austria\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 23, \"Circuit_name\": \"A1-Ring\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 57, \"Circuit_name\": \"Zeltweg\"}, {\"Circuits_ID\": 70, \"Circuit_name\": \"Red Bull Ring\"}]}"
  },
  {
    "Country": "{\"Country\": \"Azerbaijan\", \"circuits\": [{\"Circuits_ID\": 73, \"Circuit_name\": \"Baku City Circuit\"}]}"
  },
  {
    "Country": "{\"Country\": \"Bahamas\", \"circuits\": null}"
  },
];

const outerList = document.getElementById("outerList");

data.forEach(country => {
  // parse the JSON string into an object
  const countryData = JSON.parse(country.Country);
  const countryEntry = document.createElement("li");
  countryEntry.textContent = countryData.Country;
  outerList.appendChild(countryEntry);
  
  // create circuit list if it is non-null
  if (countryData.circuits != null) {
    const innerList = document.createElement("ul");
    outerList.appendChild(innerList);
    countryData.circuits.forEach(circuit => {
      const circuitEntry = document.createElement("li");
      circuitEntry.textContent = circuit.Circuit_name;
      innerList.appendChild(circuitEntry);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id="outerList"></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much GenericUser. I guess where I went wrong was that I tried to .parse the whole JSON outpout instead of doing it one object at a time like you did. Now it all makes sense. Also thank you for writing the actual JS to load the list too, Im new to JS so it would have taken me a while to work that one out so thanks.